# Has anyone tried making custom charts with Superset as per preset.io blog?

Tags: apache-superset

So I have followed: https://preset.io/blog/2020-07-02-hello-world/ for creating a simple hello-world plugin and also followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6up5x_iRbI&t=936s

It worked really smooth in there but when I try it at my end, I run into a lot of issues. I tried running it on docker as well, still it didn't work. Pypi version seems to be outdated. Here's the error i get when I try to run `npm run prod`:

> ERROR in ./src/visualizations/presets/MainPreset.js Module not found:
> Error: Can't resolve '@superset-ui/plugin-chart-hello-world' in
> '/home/spidey/apache_superset/superset-dev/incubator-superset/superset-frontend/src/visualizations/presets'

When I open the MainPreset.js file:

Here is how it looks:
[image]
And the bottom configuration:
[image]

Going back to `superset-frontend/node-modules/@superset-ui/`
I have:
[image]

When I run `npm run dev-server`:
[image]
But since I am running it on Virtual Instance so I can't open up the browser and check, whereas when I try `npm run prod` the error still persists:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow `npm link` doesn't seem to work. Resolved by copying the `chart-plugin-hello-world` file directly to the `superset-frontend/node-modules/@superset-ui/` directory. This is some issue with `npm link` hope it resolves in future.

Answer (score 1):

I have a *suspicion* of what's happening here. Is it possible that your plugin is not in `superset-frontend/package.json`?

Note that if you put your hello-world plugin in package.json, and THEN do `npm install`, the `npm install` won't work. It's frustrating, but you need to do these things in the correct order:

1. `npm install` (this nukes any npm links)
2. add the plugin to your package.json (version number doesn't really matter)
3. do the `npm link ../../......` routine
4. `npm run dev-server`

Hope that helps, but I'll continue to try to help wherever I'm able.

Comment: npm run dev-server ends with the message: `ℹ ｢wdm｣:    5951 modules ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.` The error comes when I try to run npm run prod. Is there any specific build process involved?

Comment: Ahh, yes... prod would be a different, I think. NPM Links would not be included in the bundle, I don't think. The plugin would have to be published as part of `superset-ui` for that to work, which would then include it in the actual node-modules copy of superset-ui. Your copying it into that folder effectively short circuits that, placing the files there.